# Create Index on Collection and then Rename Collection

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

Listed is the current workflow in our system

- Create Collection with name TMP_xxxx.
- Create Index on TMP_xxx (background mode).
- After all documents are written, then rename collection to XXX (for
  transactional read consistency).

When a collection is renamed, are index re-mapped to the new name or should a reindex operation be triggered?

We frequently notice this error

```
2015-05-24T21:27:18.667+0000 I INDEX    [repl index builder 1262] build index done.  scanned 34 total records. 0 secs
**2015-05-24T21:27:18.668+0000 E INDEX    [repl index builder 1299] IndexBuilder could not build index: Location28550 Unable to complete index build as the collection is no longer readable**
2015-05-24T21:27:18.668+0000 I -        [repl index builder 1299] Fatal Assertion 28555
2015-05-24T21:27:18.711+0000 I CONTROL  [repl index builder 1299]
```

Does this imply that , the collection was renamed prior to the index creation?

We recently switched to the `WiredTiger` storage engine and have begun to notice this issue.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29971616), it should be OK.